# how to get the data on Samsung bluetooth4.0 with Android4.2

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy

I had developed ios for write/read the data from LE device . Now I need to build a android app for write and get the data from same le device.

I already connected the Le device,but is will show status code is 6 or 129 when I write the data to remote device. and it never invoke Onchar...Change() callback.

So , Could you advise how I can get the data from LE device.

PS： I using S4 ,Android4.2.2, samsung BLE 2.0 SDK.

Comment: Can't you use Android 4.3 who has a full support for BLE?

Comment: Hi, My company need build it for android4.2 first. as you know Android4.3 just release ,so ...

Comment: Ok. It was just a suggestion, since BLE is now supported from Android 4.3, and not each manufacturer (Motorola, Samsung, etc.) which lead to various app with each API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I know in the feature maybe each manufacturer will update their system to Android4.3.  But now we need 4.2 for most of S4/S3 users.

Comment: any bode know ??need help

Comment: You should provide more information , like the status of discovering services, permission of characteristic, etc.

Comment: Hi All,   we fixed it out , We found we need to enable Indication switch for ALL SERVICES UUID.